# nested text in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am struggling with regular expressions. I`m having problems getting my head wrapped around similar text nested within larger text. Perhaps you can help me unclutter my thinking.

Here is an example test string:

`message msgName { stuff { innerStuff } } \n message mn2 { junk }`

I want to pull out term (e.g., `msgName`, `mn2`) and what follows until the next message, to get a list like this:

```
msgName 
{ stuff { innerStuff } more stuff } 
mn2 
{ junk }'
```

I am having trouble with too greedily or non-greedily matching to retain the inner brackets but split apart the higher level messages.

Here is one program:

```
import re
text = 'message msgName { stuff { innerStuff } more stuff } \n message mn2 { junk }'
messagePattern = re.compile('message (.*?) {(.*)}', re.DOTALL)
messageList = messagePattern.findall(text)
print "messages:\n"
count = 0
for message, msgDef in messageList:
    count = count + 1
    print str(count)
    print message
    print msgDef
```

It produces:

```
messages:

1
msgName
 stuff { innerStuff } more stuff } 
 message mn2 { junk
```

Here is my next attempt, which makes the inner part non-greedy:

```
import re
text = 'message msgName { stuff { innerStuff } more stuff } \n message mn2 { junk }'
messagePattern = re.compile('message (.*?) {(.*?)}', re.DOTALL)
messageList = messagePattern.findall(text)
print "messages:\n"
count = 0
for message, msgDef in messageList:
    count = count + 1
    print str(count)
    print message
    print msgDef
```

It produces:

```
messages:

1
msgName
 stuff { innerStuff 
2
mn2
 junk
```

So, I lose `} more stuff }`

I've really run into a mental block on this. Could someone point me in the right direction? I`m failing to deal with text in nested brackets. A suggestion as to a working regular expression or a simpler example of dealing with nested, similar text would be helpful.

Comment: I think this question deserves a little bit of time spent on the mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So, the point is to obtain a word character chunk followed with a balanced number of `{....}`, right? Something like [`(\w+)\s*({(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*})`](https://regex101.com/r/tN0nM8/1)? To use this approach, you need a PyPi regex module. Else, write a parser. Or - if you are sure there is only one nested level, use a workaround: [`(\w+)\s*{[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}`](https://regex101.com/r/tN0nM8/2) (it can be used with `re` module).

Comment: Would [`message (.*?) {(.*?)}(?: \\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mF6sC5/1) work? If there is only one nested level of `{}`, you can also use [`message (.*?) {(.*?(?:{[^}]*}).*?|.*?)}`](https://regex101.com/r/bB0yC5/1)

Comment: ^^^ @WiktorStribiżew Ooooh sub-pattern recursion, very nice! Before reading this, I thought there was no complete answer using pure regex -- and technically (in the mathematical sense) I'm right, because recursive sub-patterns aren't "regular"! Anyway... What I will say is, if you choose to use that in your code then include a helpful comment/function name to explain wtf it does :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can leverage its subroutine call support:

```
>>> import regex
>>> reg = regex.compile(r"(\w+)\s*({(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*})")
>>> s = "message msgName { stuff { innerStuff } } \n message mn2 { junk }"
>>> print(reg.findall(s))
[('msgName', '{ stuff { innerStuff } }'), ('mn2', '{ junk }')]
```

The regex - [`(\w+)\s*({(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*})`](https://regex101.com/r/tN0nM8/1) - matches:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more alphanumeric / underscore characters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace(s)
- `({(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*})` - Group 2 matching a `{`, followed with non-`{}` or another balanced `{...}` due to the `(?2)` subroutine call (recurses the whole Group 2 subpattern), 0 or more times, and then matches a closing `}`.

If there is only one nesting level, `re` can be used, too, with

```
(\w+)\s*{[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN0nM8/2)

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 matching word characters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{` - opening brace
- `[^{}]*` - 0+ characters other than `{` and `}`
- `(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `{`- opening brace
  - `[^{}]*`  - 0+ characters other than `{` and `}`
  - `}`  - closing brace
  - `[^{}]*`  - 0+ characters other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - closing brace

Comment: Wiktor, Thank you very much. This works, and I learned some things.

Comment: Great, that is what we are here for. :) I also have learned a lot.